# How to “redirect” from main page in Prestashop to specific product page?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, prestashop

This question is the same one that was asked on Feb 24.

I applied the answer using my site product page which is:

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.papasworkshop.net/home/8-the-lifter-scrollsaw-arm-lift-assembly.html
```

The error message I receive is WEBPAGE NOT AVAILABLE

The URL line contains:
`http://www.papasworkshop.net/home/8-the-lifter-scrollsaw-arm-lift-assembly.htmlhome/8-the-lifter-scrollsaw-arm-lift-assembly.html`  (and all of this text- except for the web address - repeats many many times on the URL line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `RedirectMatch` instead because `Redirect` links two different path nodes together. Meaning, `/` gets symbolically linked to `http://www.papasworkshop.net/home/8-the-lifter-scrollsaw-arm-lift-assembly.html`
. Thus anything after the `/` also appears at the end of `http://www.papasworkshop.net/home/8-the-lifter-scrollsaw-arm-lift-assembly.html`.

Incidentally, that means you're browser will continue to loop and constantly get redirected by the server. So try:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ http://www.papasworkshop.net/home/8-the-lifter-scrollsaw-arm-lift-assembly.html
```

Comment: Jon, many thanks, the fix you suggested works perfectly.  At first it didn't work and I remembered I had added the www. to my site URL when I was experimenting.  So I took it out and the redirect worked fine.  I was getting some 404 errors though and I thought it was because of your fix.  However it was the Friendly URL Setting that  I had changed in my site last night when I was experimenting. For some reason the Friendly URL setting causes problems on my site so I turned it off.  Everything seems to work great now.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @user2741612 Also keep in mind that 301 redirects get cached by the browser so you need to clear that when testing redirects. Also you should mark the answer (green checkmark) so that your question shows as resolved

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a .htaccess file in the /home subdirectory with the following line:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Comment: `Redirect` is part of mod_alias, and has nothing to do with the rewrite engine

Comment: Shylo, "RewriteEngine On" was already in my .htaccess file.  The RedirectMatch solution from Jon Lin fixed my problem.  Thanks for your input.